Ways of assigning 4 positions to 30 students, with each student receiving exactly 2 positions
There are 4 positions --- Head of math department, head of physics department, head of music department, head of philosophy department. We have 30 students who are all equally qualified for all these positions. We are required to fill these positions with 2 students, each student taking up exactly 2 positions. How many ways can this be done?
My first attempt: Choose 2 from 30, and let them each pick 2 positions. That's 30C2 × 4C2 × 1 = 2610
My second attempt: Choose 1 from 30, and let this student pick 2 positions. Then pick another student from the remaining 29, and this student takes the remaining 2. That's 30C1 × 4C2 × 29C1 × 1 = 5220.
Which one is correct and why?

Your first attempt is correct. Notice, in your second attempt, that you put importance on which student is taken first, where as this should not be important. As an example, if you pick student 1 and they choose to be the head of the math and philosophy department and then student two is chosen to be the head of the remaining two; this is the same as picking student two first and him choosing to be the head of the music and physics department with student one being chosen to be the other head. Because the two are equivalent, they should only be counted once. Therefore your second answer its twice as large as it should be so if you divide it by two, it matches your result from your first attempt.
